# What is a difference beetween artifactId spring boot and artifactId spring boot starter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to make an application that uses spring boot and I wanted to use `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in my main class of application.

I noticed that the library with artifactId spring-boot does not have this annotation, but a library with artifactId spring-boot-starter does have.

So, I am curious now about what is a difference between artifactId spring boot and artifactId spring boot starter.

**Links:**

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.9.RELEASE) of the `spring-boot-starter`, you will find that it contains `spring-boot` project. `spring-boot-starter` is considered the basic starter for spring boot projects. Like any other starter, it simplifies the configuration of your project. There are many other [starters](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-starters) for web, security, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot starter it contain pom file which contain spring-boot , spring-boot-autoconfigure, spring-boot-starter-logging,javax.annotation-api and spring core dependencies whereas in spring boot you will find all the source java file like webservice, web,validation,util,security etc.. of spring you can check by downloading their source jar